# CGLayerCreateWithContext CGContext leak

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, cgcontext

**Why is this leak occurring?**

I very much dislike the idea of asking a question that's very specific and unlikely to help very many other people but after hours of scratching my head I'm left with no option.

The leaks instrument reports that the following code has a leak:

```
- (void)likeABarrelFullOfHoles
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(50.0f, 50.0f), YES, 0.0f);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGLayerRef *shapeLayers = malloc(3 * sizeof(*shapeLayers));

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        // Leak culprit.
        shapeLayers[i] = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f), NULL);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        free(shapeLayers[i]);
    }
    free(shapeLayers);

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Specifically, it reports that the `CGLayerCreateWithContext` function is the problem but that it's leaking [CGContext](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html) objects and not [CGLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGLayer/Reference/reference.html) objects, which it returns:

[image: Leaks]
[image: Leaks]

I don't doubt that my problem is due to a fundamental lack of understanding of memory management/dynamic allocation and someone is going to wave their 'you should know this' finger at me because the following code appears to have no leaks:

```
- (void)noLeaks
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(50.0f, 50.0f), YES, 0.0f);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGLayerRef shapeLayer = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f), NULL);
    CGLayerRelease(shapeLayer);

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

---

Please note that this is obviously the problem reduced to its simplest reproducible state. I'm using dynamic memory allocation because in my actual code the size of the array isn't known at compile time.

Comment: It seems you are using free() instead of CGLayerRelease() in the first example, if this is indeed the case that might be your problem ;) (I'm talking about the for loop obviously)

Comment: @Taum Your exactly right, school boy error. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot tell you why Instruments reports that `CGContext` objects are leaking, and not `CGLayer`, but the layer created with

```
shapeLayers[i] = CGLayerCreateWithContext(context, CGSizeMake(5.0f, 5.0f), NULL);
```

must definitely be released with

```
CGLayerRelease(shapeLayers[i]);
```

and not with

```
free(shapeLayers[i]);
```

`CGLayerCreateWithContext` is not `malloc`, so calling `free` for that object can cause memory corruption.

Comment: I'm so frustrated with myself for not seeing this earlier, I think instruments reporting was throwing me off the scent. Sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes, thank you very much.